# Find limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \int_0^{x} \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi t^2}{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

I looked at the graph and found that limit is $\dfrac{1}{2}$

And limit to $-\infty$ is $-\dfrac{1}{2}$

By the way, the function for which we are finding the limit is called Fresnel function

Comment: What is your question? These are correct.

Comment: made an edit, by the way i was just curious. It may lead to some interesting discussion here on SME

Comment: This isn't really a discussion forum, though.

Comment: :O, can you give some idea wat it is exactly, or can you point me to some link

Comment: If you want to prove this result, the usual method is to look at a complex integral of $\exp(-z^2)$.  Look up *Fresnel integral*.

Comment: @user155188 http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: thanks potato, i see my question doesn't really violate much, if anything

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea is to combine the [fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx=\Big(\tfrac1n\Big)!$ with [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), arriving at

$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\cos(x^n)dx=\Big(\tfrac1n\Big)!\cdot\cos\frac\pi{2n}~$ and $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sin(x^n)dx=\Big(\tfrac1n\Big)!\cdot\sin\frac\pi{2n}~$ for $n>1$. Then for

$n=2$ [we have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function) $\Big(\tfrac12\Big)!=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2$ , and by substituting $u^2=\dfrac\pi2\cdot t^2$ we finally arrive at the desired

result.

Comment: someone give this guy a medal